# How to view all Work Items in TFS 2012 Browser

Tags: tfs

When logged on to the TFS 2012 Browser and on the Work Item screen it only shows the Work Items assigned to you.

[image: This is a screen shot of my view from the Work Items page]

I am currently logged in as the Admin of the project and have all rights. But it only shows the Work Items that are assigned to me. Is there anyway that I can view all Work Items created for the project? Or possibly filter through the other users Work Items without logging in as them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are viewing a query called "Assigned to me."  Create a new query for all work items and view that instead, or select a different query under the "Shared Queries" section at the bottom left of your screenshot.